# How are we able to access value from Node class in the DLL class

Tags: python, algorithm, oop

Can someone explain how are we able to access `value` in class DoublyLinkedList even when it is an attribute of class Node.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None 


class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        self.head = new_node 
        self.tail = new_node
        self.length = 1


    def print_list(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.value)
            temp = temp.next
```

Pls look `temp.value` of print_list function

Comment: That's because `temp` is `self.head` which is of class `Node`.

Comment: @btilly can you pls elaborate a bit?

Comment: see `print(temp)`, `print( type(temp) )`, `print( dir(temp) )`

Comment: see all your code: in `print_list` you have `temp = self.head` and in `__init__` you have `self.head = new_node` and `new_node = Node(value)` - so together you have `temp = self.head = new_node = Node(value)` which finally means `temp = Node(value)`. So your `temp` is a `Node` and you can get its `value` using `temp.value`